# Problems loading C libraries

Tags: android, android-ndk, signals

I have a problem, i get this error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "signal" referenced by "libmylib.so"...` when i execute the next code:

```
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_receiver);
```

This code is into a library which needs to capture the `SIGTERM`. The `Android.mk` content is the next one:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mylib.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

The `signal.h` include on `mylib.c` is declared too. Im coding for Android apps using Android NDK.

I thinks it's something that I'm not including into the `libmylib.so` at compile time, but i cannot see what it is.

Thank you all!!

Comment: You mention signal.h, but where is the implementation? You may want to provide a bit more context/example of the symbol in question.

Comment: signal.h it's a C language library.

Answer (score 0):

arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -x libc.so|grep signal

```
00009ab8 g     F .text  00000014 bsd_signal
0000b6ec g     F .text  00000014 pthread_cond_signal
0000c6a0 g     F .text  00000014 strsignal
0000c880 g     F .text  00000014 sysv_signal
00009ab8 <bsd_signal>:
0000b6ec <pthread_cond_signal>:
0000c6a0 <strsignal>:
0000c880 <sysv_signal>:
```

cat signal.h

```
/* the default is bsd */
static __inline__ __sighandler_t signal(int s, __sighandler_t f)
{
    return bsd_signal(s,f);
}
```

so, my inference is, it is trying to find "signal()" in you library but actually it is defined as inline function in `signal.h` and calls "bsd_signal()" and bionic contain "bsd_signal()".

Comment: Anyway, i can't use bsd_signal 'cause there isn't a reference to that function.